# Not able to change the state with event handlers in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, tsx

```
const [isToSave, setisToSave] = React.useState(false)
const myStateRef = React.useRef(isToSave);
React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('set-is-to-save', () => {
        setisToSave(!myStateRef.current)
    }, false);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('set-is-to-save', () => {
            setisToSave(!myStateRef.current)
        });
    }
}, [])

function handleOnClick(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>): void {
    myStateRef.current=!isToSave
    setisToSave(myStateRef.current)
}
```

`handleOnClick` function is called by the onClick for one of the component and it seems to be working fine. But, whenever I try to change the state from independent components using event triggers, the state of `isToSave` doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

For this simple usecase, you dont have to maintain state using `useRef`:

You can look at my quick test on my code that triggers a custom event here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-https-4q6wd?file=/src/App.js

Basically if you use the state update with callback, it should work:

```
window.addEventListener('set-is-to-save', () => {
    setisToSave((val) => !val)
}, false);
```

P.S: Be careful with custom events and security. If the communication is within same application, you should be using context or other state management.

Comment: I tried this but this seems to not working. The state update function `setisToSave` is somehow not working. 

Actually I am trying to communicate between two independent components, if not custom event then what should I use?

Comment: Did you check the code sandbox with sample code? From the developer console if you trigger the same windows.dispatchEv3nt it should work. That's one thing. And you should probably use the React context.

Comment: The event trigger is not the problem. I did check the sample code. The issue is when I am passing the updated state to `setisToSave`, it is not updating the state.

Comment: Okay. Not sure how I can help. I have the exact code as yours except for the state name.